# About the use of signed integers in C family of languages

Tags: c, coding-style, integer

When using integer values in my own code, I always try to consider the signedness, asking myself if the integer should be signed or unsigned.

When I'm sure the value will never need to be negative, I then use an unsigned integer.
And I have to say this happen most of the time.

When reading other peoples' code, I rarely see unsigned integers, even if the represented value can't be negative.

So I asked myself: **«is there a good reason for this, or do people just use signed integers because the don't care»**?

I've search on the subject, here and in other places, and I have to say I can't find a good reason not to use unsigned integers, when it applies.

I came across those questions: [«Default int type: Signed or Unsigned?»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555154/default-int-type-signed-or-unsigned), and «[Should you always use 'int' for numbers in C, even if they are non-negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259413/should-you-always-use-int-for-numbers-in-c-even-if-they-are-non-negative)» which both present the following example:

```
for( unsigned int i = foo.Length() - 1; i >= 0; --i ) {}
```

To me, this is just bad design. Of course, it may result in an infinite loop, with unsigned integers.
But is it so hard to check if `foo.Length()` is 0, before the loop?

So I personally don't think this is a good reason for using signed integers all the way.

Some people may also say that signed integers may be useful, even for non-negative values, to provide an error flag, usually `-1`.

Ok, that's good to have a specific value that means «error».
But then, what's wrong with something like `UINT_MAX`, for that specific value?

I'm actually asking this question because it may lead to some huge problems, usually when using third-party libraries.

In such a case, you often have to deal with signed and unsigned values.

Most of the time, people just don't care about the signedness, and just assign a, for instance, an `unsigned int` to a `signed int`, without checking the range.

I have to say I'm a bit [paranoid with the compiler warning flags](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122608/clang-warning-flags-for-objective-c-development), so with my setup, such an implicit cast will result in a compiler error.

For that kind of stuff, I usually use a function or macro to check the range, and then assign using an explicit cast, raising an error if needed.

This just seems logical to me.

As a last example, as I'm also an Objective-C developer (note that this question is not related to Objective-C only):

```
- ( NSInteger )tableView: ( UITableView * )tableView numberOfRowsInSection: ( NSInteger )section;
```

For those not fluent with Objective-C, `NSInteger` is a signed integer.
This method actually retrieves the number of rows in a table view, for a specific section.

The result will **never** be a negative value (as the section number, by the way).

So why use a signed integer for this?
I really don't understand.

This is just an example, but I just always see that kind of stuff, with C, C++ or Objective-C.

So again, I'm just wondering if people just don't care about that kind of problems, or if there is finally a **good** and **valid** reason not to use unsigned integers for such cases.

Looking forward to hear your answers : )

Comment: Maybe programmers are generally lazy and don't want to write "unsigned" for things where it really doesn't matter?

Comment: I usually use signed types. The only time i consider whether to use unsigned types is when I am working with microcontrollers and other embedded systems.

It is nice to another fellow developer what is "warning paranoid" ;-)

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I'm afraid you're right, but I asked the question to be sure. If that's really the case, I personally think this is just bad coding, especially for people who write libraries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should you always use 'int' for numbers in C, even if they are non-negative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259413/should-you-always-use-int-for-numbers-in-c-even-if-they-are-non-negative)

Comment: Did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/336/612920

Comment: @Mansuro Yes... Not a valid reason to me, hence my question.

Comment: This has been discussed several times (and SO is not really the place for discussion but for answers), so I voted to close this. Discussions on this tend to be quite ideological and not very fruitful. This doesn't mean at all that I don't agree with you, though, the type that I personally use most is `size_t`.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt This question is basically the same that the one I quote in my question. Not a valid answer, IMHO.

Comment: How would you handle a legitimate return value of `UINT_MAX` if you are using it as your error return?

Comment: @sarnold In such a case, `UINT_MAX` won't be a legitimate return value (exactly as the kind of convention with signed integers where a negative value indicates an error). But then you don't sacrifice the whole range, just for an error flag.

Comment: I have to agree with Jens, this is not the place for discussions. This doesn't necessarily mean I agree with his overuse of unsigned values though ;-)

Comment: @JensGustedt The use of `size_t` and how you introduce it early on in "Modern C" as the correct type to use when iterating over arrays, is one of the things I really liked with that book. Not only because `int i` might be too small to contain the size of an array, but also because as mentioned in the book, unsigned arithmetic is always well-defined. The arguments you raised there (chapter 4) were sound and rational, not ideological. If there's a right and a wrong to a discussion, it is not subjective, but facts versus misguided believes. So I see no reason to close this question. ->

Comment: Rather, it is questions like this that programmers need to ask and getting input about the topic from others is very valuable. There's lots of incorrect answers posted, certainly, but just down vote them in that case.

Comment: @Lundin, this question here is 5 years old and in particular predates the availability of my book by far. AFAIR there have been other question on the subject since then that handle it quite well, so maybe we should try to merge these or put it into the C documentation track or so.

Comment: @JensGustedt Oops, I actually didn't notice the dates, someone must have poked it back to life. Anyway, if there are similar questions then maybe one of them has better answers and we can close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When using integer values in my own code, I always try to consider the signedness, asking myself if the integer should be signed or unsigned.
>
> When I'm sure the value will never need to be negative, I then use an unsigned integer.
> And I have to say this happen most of the time.

To carefully consider which type that is most suitable each time you declare a variable is very good practice! This means you are careful and professional. You should not only consider signedness, but also the potential max value that you expect this type to have.

The reason why you shouldn't use signed types when they aren't needed have nothing to do with performance, but with type safety. There are lots of potential, subtle bugs that can be caused by signed types:

- The various forms of implicit promotions that exist in C can cause your type to change signedness in unexpected and possibly dangerous ways. *The integer promotion rule* that is part of *the usual arithmetic conversions*, the *lvalue conversion* upon assignment, *the default argument promotions* used by for example VA lists, and so on.
- When using any form of bitwise operators or similar hardware-related programming, signed types are dangerous and can easily cause various forms of undefined behavior.

By declaring your integers unsigned, you automatically skip past a whole lot of the above dangers. Similarly, by declaring them as large as `unsigned int` or larger, you get rid of lots of dangers caused by the integer promotions.

Both size and signedness are important when it comes to writing rugged, portable and safe code. This is the reason why you should always use the types from `stdint.h` and not the native, so-called "primitive data types" of C.

---

> So I asked myself: «is there a good reason for this, or do people just use signed integers because the don't care»?

I don't really think it is because they don't care, nor because they are lazy, even though declaring everything `int` is sometimes referred to as "sloppy typing" - which means sloppily picked type more than it means too lazy to type.

I rather believe it is because they lack deeper knowledge of the various things I mentioned above. There's a frightening amount of seasoned C programmers who don't know how implicit type promotions work in C, nor how signed types can cause poorly-defined behavior when used together with certain operators.

This is actually a very frequent source of subtle bugs. Many programmers find themselves staring at a compiler warning or a peculiar bug, which they can make go away by adding a cast. But they don't understand why, they simply add the cast and move on.

---

> for( unsigned int i = foo.Length() - 1; i >= 0; --i ) {}
>
> To me, this is just bad design

Indeed it is.

Once upon a time, down-counting loops would yield more effective code, because the compiler pick add a "branch if zero" instruction instead of a "branch if larger/smaller/equal" instruction - the former is faster. But this was at a time when compilers were really dumb and I don't believe such micro-optimizations are relevant any longer.

So there is rarely ever a reason to have a down-counting loop. Whoever made the argument probably just couldn't think outside the box. The example could have been rewritten as:

```
for(unsigned int i=0; i<foo.Length(); i++)
{
  unsigned int index = foo.Length() - i - 1;
  thing[index] = something;
}
```

This code should not have any impact on performance, but the loop itself turned a whole lot easier to read, while at the same time fixing the bug that your example had.

As far as performance is concerned nowadays, one should probably spend the time pondering about which form of data access that is most ideal in terms of data cache use, rather than anything else.

---

> Some people may also say that signed integers may be useful, even for non-negative values, to provide an error flag, usually -1.

That's a poor argument. Good API design uses a dedicated error type for error reporting, such as an enum.

Instead of having some hobbyist-level API like

```
int do_stuff (int a, int b); // returns -1 if a or b were invalid, otherwise the result
```

you should have something like:

```
err_t do_stuff (int32_t a, int32_t b, int32_t* result);

// returns ERR_A is a is invalid, ERR_B if b is invalid, ERR_XXX if... and so on
// the result is stored in [result], which is allocated by the caller
// upon errors the contents of [result] remain untouched
```

The API would then consistently reserve the return of every function for this error type.

(And yes, many of the standard library functions abuse return types for error handling. This is because it contains lots of ancient functions from a time before good programming practice was invented, and they have been preserved the way they are for backwards-compatibility reasons. So just because you find a poorly-written function in the standard library, you shouldn't run off to write an equally poor function yourself.)

---

Overall, it sounds like you know what you are doing and giving signedness some thought. That probably means that knowledge-wise, you are actually already ahead of the people who wrote those posts and guides you are referring to.

The Google style guide for example, is questionable. Similar could be said about lots of other such coding standards that use "proof by authority". Just because it says Google, NASA or Linux kernel, people blindly swallow them no matter the quality of the actual contents. There are good things in those standards, but they also contain subjective opinions, speculations or blatant errors.

Instead I would recommend referring to real professional coding standards instead, such as [MISRA-C](https://www.misra.org.uk/). It enforces lots of thought and care for things like signedness, type promotion and type size, where less detailed/less serious documents just skip past it.

There is also [CERT C](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/SEI+CERT+C+Coding+Standard), which isn't as detailed and careful as MISRA, but at least a sound, professional document (and more focused towards desktop/hosted development).

Comment: Excellent answer, best of the ones given when writing this comment! Have a counter-example for the downcounting loops, though: encoding data with COBS; you are much more efficient if doing it from behind...

Answer (score 5):

- a `signed` return value might yield more information (think error-numbers, `0` is sometimes a valid answer, `-1` indicates error, see `man read`) ... which might be relevant especially for developers of libraries.
- if you are worrying about the one extra bit you gain when using `unsigned` instead of `signed` then you are probably using the wrong type anyway. (also kind of "premature optimization" argument)
- languages like python, ruby, jscript etc are doing just fine without `signed` vs `unsigned`. that might be an indicator ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I said in the question, why should we use -1 for an error flag, when we could use UINT_MAX?

Comment: Because the distinction between positive-negative conveys more information than the implicit small_value-big_value distinction.

Comment: Actually, I have seen code that used `~0` instead of  `-1` to represent an error value.

Comment: @Macmade: a) with `UINT_MAX` you have only one error-code. with `-2` i have another one, just like that. b) UINT_MAX might be defined differently on the machine that is using the "library" than it was defined when compiling the "library"; `-1` is always `-1` (except for implicit cast to unsigned :))

Answer (score 2):

There is one heavy-weight argument against widely unsigned integers:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

We all have at least on one occasion been bitten by unsigned integers. Sometimes like in your loop, sometimes in other contexts. Unsigned integers add a hazard, even though a small one, to your program. And you are introducing this hazard to change the meaning of **one bit**. One little, tiny, insignificant-but-for-its-sign-meaning bit. On the other hand, the integers we work with in bread and butter applications are often far below the range of integers, more in the order of 10^1 than 10^7. Thus, the different range of unsigned integers is in the vast majority of cases not needed. And when it's needed, it is quite likely that this extra bit won't cut it (when 31 is too little, 32 is rarely enough) and you'll need a wider or an arbitrary-wide integer anyway. The pragmatic approach in these cases is to just use the signed integer and spare yourself the occasional underflow bug. Your time as a programmer can be put to much better use.

Comment: I totally agree with the quote. But do you really think that using unsigned values is a premature optimization?

Comment: @Macmade: If it is unproven that a plain int, which is less error-prone, will suffice: Yes, then I think using unsigned is premature.

Comment: Not sure I totally agree yet, but that's a good answer anyway. Thanks : )

Comment: @thiton Why do you consider that `unsigned` is an optimization over `int`? Is it only because the default is `int`? I have been bitten by signed ints when array indexes went below 0. With unsigned the error would have been immediate with a segmentation fault.

Comment: By the way, isn't saying that you won't need more than 10^1 also a kind of premature optimization?

Comment: In my book, signed types are for things that can be negative, unsigned for things that can't. Plain simple. And most of the things in my practice are never negative. There are certain dangers involved with using each of them and especially all of them together, but guess what? Thou shalt know thy tools. And that applies to everyone, those who'd rather use signed, those who'd rather use unsigned and those who use both. There's no hazard if you're informed and aren't guessing what the compiler can and will do.

Comment: I don't see at all what this has to do with premature optimization. unsigned integers are part of the language just as signed ones. Just use the correct type at the right time.

Comment: @mouviciel: I think you should rather use bound checking in such case. Unsigned integer won't heal problems with other end of the array anyway.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Unsigned integer types which are at least as large as int have consistent defined wrapping behavior; those which are smaller have mostly-consistent defined wrapping behavior.  Integer types as large as int have no defined wrapping behavior, while those which are smaller sometimes have wrapping defined behavior.

Comment: I have never been bitten by unsigned types, but gotten chewed at pretty badly by signed types. And indeed, optimization has nothing to do with this what-so-ever.

Answer (score 1):

From the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com):

The [first question in the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/decl/inttypes.html) is which integer type should we decide to use?

> If you might need large values (above 32,767 or below -32,767), use long. Otherwise, if space is very important (i.e. if there are large arrays or many structures), use short. Otherwise, use int. If well-defined overflow characteristics are important and negative values are not, or if you want to steer clear of sign-extension problems when manipulating bits or bytes, use one of the corresponding unsigned types.

Another question concerns types conversions:

> If an operation involves both signed and unsigned integers, the situation is a bit more complicated. If the unsigned operand is smaller (perhaps we're operating on unsigned int and long int), such that the larger, signed type could represent all values of the smaller, unsigned type, then the unsigned value is converted to the larger, signed type, and the result has the larger, signed type. Otherwise (that is, if the signed type can not represent all values of the unsigned type), both values are converted to a common unsigned type, and the result has that unsigned type.

You can find it [here](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html). So basically using unsigned integers, mostly for arithmetic conversions can complicate the situation since you'll have to either make all your integers unsigned, or be at the risk of confusing the compiler and yourself, but as long as you know what you are doing, this is not really a risk per se. However, it could introduce simple bugs.

And when it is a good to use unsigned integers? one situation is when using bitwise operations:

> The << operator shifts its first operand left by a number of bits
>   given by its second operand, filling in new 0 bits at the right.
>   Similarly, the >> operator shifts its first operand right. If the
>   first operand is unsigned, >> fills in 0 bits from the left, but if
>   the first operand is signed, >> might fill in 1 bits if the high-order
>   bit was already 1. (Uncertainty like this is one reason why it's
>   usually a good idea to use all unsigned operands when working with the
>   bitwise operators.)

taken from [here](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4ab.html)
And I've seen this somewhere:

> If it was best to use unsigned integers for values that are never negative, we would have started by using unsigned int in the main function `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. One thing is sure, argc is never negative.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comments, the signature of `main` is due to historical reasons and apparently it predates the existence of the unsigned keyword.

Comment: This is isn't much of a good point to it. If you (almost) always use unsigned values for integer arithmetic this disappears.

Comment: Your quote on `main` doesn't make much sense to me. The signature of `main` is there for historical reasons only. It predates even the existence oof the `unsigned` keyword in the C language. The C standards committee is very conservative in not breaking existing code.

Comment: "So basically using unisgned integers will complicate the situation since you'll have to either make all your integers unsigned, or be at the risk of confusing the compiler and yourself." You are misunderstanding this. Take code like `255 << 8`, this is problematic because `255` is a signed type. On a 8 or 16 bit system, this code would cause undefined behavior as it shifts data into the sign bits. A bug that could have been avoided by using `(unsigned int)255` or `255u`. Similarly, `uint8_t x=255; ... x << 8` causes the very same bug, because of integer promotion _to_ a signed type.

Comment: The text cited refers to the usual arithmetic conversions though. The problem mentioned is mixing signed and unsigned types without care, which should be solved by 1) actually giving thought to what you are doing, and 2) enable compiler warnings/use static analysis tools

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned intgers are an artifact from the past. This is from the time, where processors could do unsigned arithmetic a little bit faster.

This is a case of *premature optimization* which is considered evil.

Actually, in 2005 when AMD introduced x86_64 (or AMD64, how it was then called), the 64 bit architecture for x86, they brought the ghosts of the past back: If a signed integer is used as an index and the compiler can not prove that it is never negative, is has to insert a 32 to 64 bit sign extension instruction - because the default 32 to 64 bit extension is *unsigned* (the upper half of a 64 bit register gets cleard if you move a 32 bit value into it).

But I would recommend against using *unsigned* in any arithmetic at all, being it pointer arithmetic or just simple numbers.

`for( unsigned int i = foo.Length() - 1; i >= 0; --i ) {}`

Any recent compiler will warn about such an construct, with *condition ist always true* or similar. With using a signed variable you avoid such pitfalls at all. Instead use `ptrdiff_t`.

A problem might be the c++ library, it often uses an unsigned type for `size_t`, which is required because of some rare corner cases with very large sizes (between 2^31 and 2^32) on 32 bit systems with certain boot switches ( /3GB windows).

There are many more, comparisons between signed and unsigned come to my mind, where the signed value automagically gets promoted to a unsigned and thus becomes a huge positive number, when it has been a small negative before.

One exception for using `unsigned` exists: For bit fields, flags, masks it is quite common. Usually it doesn't make sense at all to interpret the value of these variables as a magnitude, and the reader may deduce from the type that this variable is to be interpreted in bits.

> The result will never be a negative value (as the section number, by the way). So why use a signed integer for this?

Because you might want to compare the return value to a signed value, which is actually negative. The comparison should return *true* in that case, but the C standard specifies that the signed get promoted to an unsigned in that case and you will get a *false* instead. I don't know about ObjectiveC though.

Comment: Unsigned integers are _awesome_ for bit-masking and well-defined overflow behavior, not so good for arithmetic. Different tools for different jobs...

Comment: When your program relies on the extra bit of precision but can't afford the extra 32 bits of the next larger type, you are in a very dangerous area anyway. In this case you can safely assume you are knowing what you a doing (because you would never run into trouble open-eyed, wouldn't you), and if you know what you do you can surely use unsigned :-)

Comment: @Macmade: Is the example where a comparison might give you a wrong result when you don't expect it not a valid reason in your book?

Comment: "Unsigned intgers are an artifact from the past" historically this simply incorrect. At the beginning just had signed integer types.

Comment: Your point is just bogus. There is clearly a problem when signed and unsigned values are used inconsistently, you may have implicit conversions and stuff like that, agreed. But this doesn't mean that the evil is on one side.

Comment: @Jens Gusted: So you recommend using _unsigned_ for values which can only have positive values (like sizes) and _signed_ for numbers which might be negative? If so, how do you avoid troubles like the implicit conversion to unsigned?

Comment: `size_t` is often an unsigned type? You are kidding. `size_t` is **defined** to be an unsigned type. And this has a reason, that has nothing to do with the range of the type. The semantic of `sizeof` is that it is always a positive value.

Comment: If you keep your types correct, such comparisons shouldn't occur. If I use `size_t` for indexing in an array and `intmax_t` to count money, I should rarely be tempted to compare them.

Comment: So assume you provide storage space, whose size can of course be only positive (_size_t_), to a customer. The customer pays you for that, and you are using _intmax_t_ for his account balance. Don't you think it could remotely be possible that a programmer might compare this two values? You avoid all this hassle by using int. But you fail to provide an argument for _unsigned_, so what exactly is the evil inside a _signed_ value?

Comment: Why would someone compare such values. If you'd have to compute a price from a resource usage, you don't have any hidden conversion, you have an explicit computation from `size_t` to `intmax_t`. And not signed values as such are evil but the wrong usage of them. Just use the types with the correct semantics.

Comment: You can equally assume that the programmer does compute the allowed resource usage from the account balance, so he does calculate from intmax_t to size_t. He could think, why not multiply the account balance by a factor and compare it to the allowed resource usage of type _size_t_? This does not seem so far fetched. And of course this will fall apart, and could easily be avoided by the usage of signed values. Could you give an example where signed leads to similar problems which could be avoided by the use of unsigned?

Comment: The fundamental problem with unsigned integers is that types like `uint16_t` are tasked with three different roles: as integers where computations won't exceed their 0-65,535 limits, as storage locations for things where intermediate computations may exceed that limit but will yield a final output within it (e.g. `(x+y+z+1)/3`, where x, y, and z are all 0-65,535), and as members of a wrapping algebraic ring of integers mod 65536 (where it is expected that multiplying 65535 by 65535 will yield 1).  Use of such types may yield surprises if a compiler's behavior doesn't match the intended use.

Comment: @hirschhornsalz It will only fall apart if the programmer doesn't know what they are doing. In case `intmax_t` is larger than `size_t`, which doesn't seem unlikely, then the `size_t` operand will get converted to an `intmax_t`, which may be just as unfortunate. Suppose the purpose is calculate an array index, and you end up with a negative result because of implicit conversion to signed type? Example: `intmax_t i; size_t s; ... s = (i + s) << n`.

Comment: @supercat I really don't see how those examples would have been improved by using `unsigned int`. It would only mean that instead of portably knowing if the types will overflow, you will no longer know it. Obviously declaring all those variables `int` would have been even worse, as you would risk signed overflows. A better way to write the code would have been to make x, y and z `uint32_t`, then store the result in an `uint16_t`. Unless the system is some wildly exotic one, that code could never cause problems.

Comment: The key here is _awareness_ by the programmer of which types they use in an expression, what their maximum values are, what potential type promotions that could occur etc etc. In other words, C programming knowledge. Resorting to some dogma like "always use int" or "always use unsigned int" just because you lack knowledge doesn't seem like a very good idea.

Comment: @Lundin: Whether or not there is any logical reason why a calculation like `unsigned mul_mod_65536(uint16_t x, uint16_t y) { return (x*y) & 65535u; }` should ever have any side-effects on a two's-complement silent-wraparound hardware platform, that precise function *will* sometimes have side-effects in many versions of gcc.  Given what the authors of C89 wrote in the rationale for making unsigned short values promote as signed, I suspect even they would be surprised that code like the above would fail on modern platforms running anything other than a sanitizing build.

Comment: @supercat Whatever the reason, implicit type promotions is perhaps the single-most broken feature of the C language. The cure is programmer awareness. The bug in your posted code is of course easily prevented by casting one or both operands to `uint32_t`, which is not a small integer type on any existing system.

Comment: It can be avoided, but my point is that the C89 rationale suggests that the authors of the Standard expected that the fraction of systems needing the cast would monotonically decrease with time.  I think they would question the quality of a compiler in 2017 that neither ignores nor traps on the "overflow", but instead yields arbitrary and unpredictable side-effects.