# Why do functions take an int as an argument when its value logically can not be < 0

Tags: .net, arguments, int, uint

When I am writing functions that takes an arguments that determine a certain length, I always use `uint`. As it makes no sense for the value to be a negative number.

But I see the opposite (very often) in the .Net framework.
For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx

> Initializes a new instance of the String class to the value indicated by a specified Unicode character repeated a specified number of times.

```
public String(
    char c,
    int count
)
```

It also states that an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is thrown when `*count* is less than zero."

Why not make the `count` argument an `uint` then!?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does .NET use int instead of uint in certain classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782629/why-does-net-use-int-instead-of-uint-in-certain-classes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had [a similar question ages ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013116/should-i-use-uint-in-c-sharp-for-values-that-cant-be-negative), although more for my own interfaces, not the core ones.

The short answer (given by no other than Eric Lippert, and repeated in [answers to other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301/why-is-array-length-an-int-and-not-an-uint?rq=1)) is: The Common Language Specification rules state that you should not use `uint` in public interfaces because not all languages that are designed to work with .NET actually *have* such a type. Java derivatives like J# come to mind – Java only has signed integral types.

Comment: That thread has good info. This post also has some related information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555154/default-int-type-signed-or-unsigned

Comment: Yes, that's certainly something to consider too (and was given as an answer to my question as well), but given the history of .NET I'd say that was a smaller reason than restricting the type system to types that can work with almost all languages. That was in the late 90s / early 2000s when Microsoft still considered Java a necessary language to support.

Comment: Wow! I never heard/read of `Common Language Specification rules`. Its totally something else than good coding practise. Its feels ethical!

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned types in C have two primary usages:

1. In some cases, it is useful to have values which would "wrap" when computations exceeded the range of a type.  For example, when computing many kinds of hash or checksum it is much more convenient to simply perform a bunch of additions or multiplies while ignoring overflow, than to use an over-sized variable and/or conditional logic to prevent overflow.
2. It is sometimes useful to have a two-byte variable be able to hold a value up to 65,535 rather than just 32,767; occasionally it is useful to have four-byte variables go up to 4,294,967,295, but that's much less common.

In C, an attempt to store -1 into an `unsigned` variable was required to store (without any sort of error or squawk) the value which, when added to +1, would yield zero.  This was very useful for the first usage scenario; it wasn't desirable for the second, but since C never had any sort of overflow trapping on signed integers either it could be considered an extension of the principle that bad things will happen when computations on *numbers* (rather than algebraic rings) go out of range.

C#, unlike C, supports numeric overflow detection, and could thus apply it to the second style of use while still allowing the first style of use.  Unfortunately, the determination is made based upon checked or unchecked numerical contexts, rather than upon the types of variables, parameters, or values.  Thus, if a method were to accept a parameter of type `UInt32` and code in an `unchecked` context tried to pass in a value of -1, the method would see that as a value of 4,294,967,295.  There's no way by which a parameter can be marked to say "This should be a value between 0 and 4,294,967,295; squawk if it's anything else, *regardless of checked/unchecked status*.  It's thus safer to have code accept an `Int32` if an upper limit of 2,147,483,647 is sufficient, or `Int64` if not.